# How to run hive commands from shell?

Tags: hive, beeline

I have to repair tables in hive from my shell script after successful completion of my spark application.

```
msck repair table <DATABASE_NAME>.<TABLE_NAME>;
```

Please suggest me a suitable approach for this which also works for large tables with partitions.

Answer (score 1):

I have found a workaround for this using :

```
hive -S -e "msck repair table <DATABASE_NAME>.<TABLE_NAME>;"
```

**-S** : This silents the output generated from Hive.

**-e** : This is used for running hive command.

**-f** : This is used for providing a hql script.

Comment: You can also try `beeline`